# Multi-line title alignment using plotly

Tags: python, plotly

Is it possible to make the title have pixel-perfect alignment with the top of the image when using line breaks in the title? Normally you can do this with yanchor='top' and y=1, but line breaks in the title appear to break this.

Code:

```
layout = go.Layout(
    height=500, width=500,
    margin=dict(l=5, r=5, b=5, t=20),
    title=dict(
        text=f"<b>Test Title<br>Subtitle</b>", font_size=15, 
        x=0.5, y=1, yanchor='top', xanchor='center'),
)
data = [go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3, 4], y=[6, 5, 4, 3], mode='lines')]
chart = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plotly.offline.plot(chart)
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: I see you're using `plotly.offline.plot` which is a legacy way of using plotly and might indicate you're on an older version. Perhaps if you update to the latest version, and try e.g. [`plotly.express`](https://plotly.com/python/plotly-express/), the issue resolves itself?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I tried upgrading to the latest but it didn't fix it. What is the newer way of using plotly? I need plotly.go for other things and am just using plotly.offline.plot for testing.

Comment: I have confirmed your same event. I don't know why, but if you disable `y=1`, you will see the title with line breaks.

Comment: @r-beginners it's because the upper line of the title is being drawn above the top edge of the chart.

Comment: I just tried it through the newer way as well, but that didn't resolve your issue. It seems to be a bug you need to work around by tweaking the value of `y`. The newer way I think is either using plotly.express, or if you need more fine-grained control, build the `go.Figure` and then call the `.show()` methdo on it.